# Adjust the layout based on the device

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

This is my first android app so very new to this. My app when used in a mobile device, the layout is not shown completely. I mean to say that the buttons in end are not displayed. Using ScrollView will solve this problem. But is there any way to adjust the layout based on the device i use? And also an example code for using ScrollView would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: layout code (.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Matchdetails" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/Maledet" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_ras"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_nak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spin_ras"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spin_ras"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_gotra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spin_nak"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_pada"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spin_nak"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spin_pada"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spin_nak"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/Femdet" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spin_nak"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/Name" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_fras"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_fnak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spin_fras"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spin_fras"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_fpada"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spin_fnak"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_fgotra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spin_fpada"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spin_fnak"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="@string/Submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/Cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your layout file.

Comment: i have edited the quest with the layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your layout and put it in a scroll view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".Matchdetails" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/Maledet" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_ras"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_nak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spin_ras"
            android:layout_below="@id/spin_ras"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_gotra"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/spin_nak"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_pada"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/spin_nak"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/spin_pada"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spin_nak"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:text="@string/Femdet" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/spin_nak"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:text="@string/Name" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_fras"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_below="@id/editText2"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_fnak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/spin_fras"
            android:layout_below="@id/spin_fras"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_fpada"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/spin_fnak"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_fgotra"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/spin_fpada"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spin_fpada"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/spin_fnak"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/Submit" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
                android:text="@string/Cancel" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

A couple of things to be noted.

1. You need @+id/view_id only when you create a new View ID for the first time in your layout. When you refer an existing id you can do so with @id/view_id.
2. Avoid hard coding the values wherever possible. You will find it difficult while using your layout to fit different screens.
3. The above layout isn't perfect, but will fit your requirement. You may want to use nested views in your layout and get the hang of what the different attributes mean in the layout xml. That, you will gain by trying out different things.

In general, Designing for multiple screens involves considering a number of factors.

1. Supporting screens with different sizes and resolutions (VGA/ HVGA / WVGA/ WXGA) screens/(hdpi/mdpi..) densities.
2. Different Form factors(smartphones/tablets)
3. Different orientations(landscape/portrait) on the same device.

You should perhaps read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) for a complete know-how about designing your app for  multiple screen types. And there's a sample application in the link.

Comment: i do not own a mobile which supports android. Now if i replace my existing xml with ur xml will it work on any device irrespective of the height and width of the screen?

Comment: It should work fine. If you don't have a device, you may just try with different emulator options.

Comment: Now when i try it in a smaller emulator, the spinners i used display the first item. But when i tried it in mobile it just showed box kind of thing clicking on which it would display all dropdown items. y so?

Comment: I am not able to exactly visualize what you say. Are the android versions of the emulator and the device same?

Comment: The device i tried it on was gingerbread i guess. The properties of my app is marked Android 4.2.2

Comment: Different versions of android render the views slightly differently. My guess is that you have different behavior because of the android versions. It is fine as long as it behaves appropriately.

Comment: another problem i encountered is that my inner ScrollView doesn't work if i use this code. How can i make my inner ScrollView work?

Comment: What do you mean by inner ScrollView? Are you adding a ScrollView within this layout?

Comment: I am trying to add a ScrollView within the layout. By doing this only the ScrollView for the layout works and the ScrollView I have inside the layout does not scroll.

Comment: It usually does not work when you add a ScrollView within another. Also, It is not great to use when you have nested scrollviews in your layout. However if you still want the scrollview to work, you can find a way to do that. But then, it is inconvenient while using it.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try the compatibility layouts :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Maledet" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_ras"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_gotra"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_nak"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_pada"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/Femdet" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" />
                </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_fras"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_fgotra"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_fnak"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_fpada"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spin_fnak"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/Submit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
            android:text="@string/Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you run your project on smaller device then your content is out of device height then ScrollView make visible and i have done your achievement using LinearLayout becz it's easly handle and more convenient rather than RelativeLayout...

Comment: ur code worked too. but the buttons are displayed even before every field is entered. so iv put it in a single layout. I dint know about nesting layouts. I thank u for that

Comment: i have put button outside scroll becz when user wan to submit form so it's nerver scroll and click on button